# Are the teletubbies cyborgs?

Tags: plot-explanation, teletubbies

Look at the evidence:

[image]

As the name suggests, they have **implanted televisions!**

Were they born that way or did they undergo some fiendish experiment?

Comment: The teletubbies scare the crap out of me.

Comment: One way to find out is to use the [Voight-Kampff machine](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Blade_runner#Voight-Kampff_machine) on the Teletubbies.

Comment: I think the Teletubbies are more advanced than us and actually the TV's are wearable tech with a Velcro backing so they can be stuck on the fur. Unfortunately to pick up TV signals from the air they need antennae.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest that the Teletubbies are not cyborgs.

The peculiar antenna and visual display appendages are naturally occurring adaptations which allow them to exist in symbiotic harmony with humans.

They display a distinct and uncontrollable physiological requirement for the reception of (mostly) childrens basic and crucially, innocent thought patterns. This coupled with our own natural requirement for congnative and social development; the 'Tubbies' use their individual personalities and applicable talents to display moral and ethical guidance, through the performance of simplistic song, dance and play scenarios...

I would therefore classify them as Symbiote.